# How to display Url Image Tkinter python 3

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, url, tkinter

How can I visualize an url of an image with tkinter ("http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0374157065.01.LZZZZZZZ.jpg").I would like to place it in the last column of the program, in standard size, I tried many guides but none of them ever worked. Thanks very mutch

Comment: Have you tried searching this site for an answer? I see several questions and answers related to displaying an image from a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not bind a URL to a Label like this?

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def callback(event):
    webbrowser.open_new(r"http://www.your-image.com")

root = Tk()
link = Label(root, text="The image", fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
link.pack()
link.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
root.mainloop()
```